# Is it valid to use DISTINCT two times in a single query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm getting this following error:

**MYSQL ERROR**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DISTINCT R.`roomtype` as `roomtype` , I1.`meal_plan` as
>   `mealplan` , I1.`bed_t' at line 3

**My Code is**

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT H.`hotelname` as `hotelname` , 
    DISTINCT R.`roomtype` as `roomtype` , 
    I1.`meal_plan` as `mealplan` , 
    I1.`bed_type` as `bedtype` , 
    I1.`roomrate` as `roomrate` , 
    I1.`pax` as `pax` , 
    I1.`childrate` as `childrate` , 
    I1.`childrate1` as `childrate1` , 
    I1.`childrate2` as `childrate2` , 
    I1.`childrate3` as `childrate3` , 
    P.`profitmarkup_type` as `profit_type` , 
    P.`applyprofit_val_room` as `applyprofit_val_room` , 
    P.`applyprofit_val_bed` as `applyprofit_val_bed` 
FROM `hoteldetails` H 
INNER JOIN `roomdetails` R 
    on H.`hotelname` = R.`hotelname` 
INNER JOIN `inventorypolicy` I1 
    on I1.`hotel_name` = H.`hotelname` 
    AND I1.`room_plan` = R.`roomtype` 
    AND I1.`bed_type`=R.`bedtype` 
    AND I1.`meal_plan`=R.`mealplan` 
    AND I1.`suppliername`=H.`supplier` 
INNER JOIN `profitmarkup` P 
    on P.`hotel_name` = H.`hotelname` 
    AND P.`suppliername` = H.`supplier` 
WHERE H.`active`='1' 
    AND H.`country`='MAL' 
    AND H.`city`='KL' 
    AND H.`show2web`='1' 
    AND H.`expiry_date` >= 11/09/2014 
    AND I1.`inventory_status`='1' 
    AND P.`markup_status` = '1' 
    AND 20140911 BETWEEN ((I1.`date1`)+(I1.`month1`*100)+(I1.`year1`*10000)) AND ((I1.`date2`)+(I1.`month2`*100)+(I1.`year2`*10000)) 
    AND 20140911 BETWEEN ((P.`date1`)+(P.`month1`*100)+(P.`year1`*10000)) AND ((P.`date2`)+(P.`month2`*100)+(P.`year2`*10000))
```

I dont know how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your multiple `DISTINCT`s?

Comment: I want to filter duplicates for hotelname and roomtype

Comment: You can see that im using INNER JOIN which results in repeated values possibly duplicate values for avoiding that , im using **Distinct**

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, And dates in SQL adhere to a specific format

Comment: Thanks for ur update , i have edited my query but still getting same error @Strawberry

Comment: @Hari-pacific you can't use `DISTINCT` in that manner.  You'd use `SELECT DISTINCT..` where you have distinct listed once.  If you truly have other issues, then you probably will need to edit your question with your table structures, sample data and then the final result that you expect.

Comment: The main purpose why im using DISTINCT Twice was im getting duplicate values while using INNER JOIN (getting same value twice for same roomtype) @bluefeet

Comment: @Hari-pacific I understand the reason for it, I'm telling you that you are using it wrong - `DISTINCT` can only appear once in your select statement - at the beginning.  `DISTINCT` applies to all columns it isn't a function that applies to a single column.

Comment: Ok , Now i understood the concept anyways Thanks for your support and clarifications..

Comment: I think bluefeet has said everything that can be said here.

Answer (score 0):

As you can learn from the documentation of the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) MySQL statement, `DISTINCT` can be placed before any field or expression to be selected. This automatically forces a single instance of it in a query.

And somewhere down the road there is a sentence that says everything:

> `DISTINCTROW` is a synonym for `DISTINCT`.